# How to Round the Corners of a JavaFX PopupControl

Tags: java, javafx, popup, popupwindow

I'd like to slightly round the corners of a JavaFX PopupControl.

Below is a simple recreation of what I've tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {

    PopupControl pu = new PopupControl();
    pu.setStyle("-fx-background-radius: 10 10 10 10");
    pu.setStyle("-fx-border-radius: 10 10 10 10");

    VBox vb = new VBox();
    vb.setPrefWidth(300);
    vb.setPrefHeight(200);
    vb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(17, 230, 120, 1.0)");

    pu.getScene().setRoot(vb);
    stage.setWidth(600);
    stage.setHeight(500);
    stage.show();

    pu.show(stage);
```

Here is what's being shown:

[image]

For clarification, the corners of the green PopupControl are what I'm trying to round off.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Note that the style is a single property, so when you call `pu.setStyle(...)` twice, the second style *replaces* the previous style; it doesn't add to it.

You need to set the background radius on the same container as you set the background color. The following works:

```
public void start(Stage stage) {

    PopupControl pu = new PopupControl();

    VBox vb = new VBox();
    vb.setPrefWidth(300);
    vb.setPrefHeight(200);
    vb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(17, 230, 120, 1.0); " +
            "-fx-background-radius: 10 10 10 10 ;");


    pu.getScene().setRoot(vb);
    stage.setWidth(600);
    stage.setHeight(500);
    stage.show();

    pu.show(stage);
}
```

[image]

Setting the styles in an external style sheet is preferred, and probably easier.