# Round corner of popup window: blank corners

Tags: java, javafx, popup, popupwindow

I tried to execute the code provided in this post:
[How to Round the Corners of a JavaFX PopupControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71879089/how-to-round-the-corners-of-a-javafx-popupcontrol)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.PopupControl;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        PopupControl pu = new PopupControl();

        VBox vb = new VBox();
        vb.setPrefWidth(300);
        vb.setPrefHeight(200);
        vb.setStyle("-fx-background-color: rgba(17, 230, 120, 1.0); " +
                    "-fx-background-radius: 10;");

        Scene scene = new Scene(vb);
        pu.setScene(scene);

        stage.setWidth(600);
        stage.setHeight(500);
        stage.show();

        pu.show(stage);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I didn't have the expected result, I have blank corners on my popup, like in this image:
[image]

How to remove them and have a real rounded corner without white in the corner ?

**Edit:**

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.6 (Maipo)
- GTK 3.14.15
- openjdk version "17.0.1"
- openjfx version "17.0.1"

Comment: Cannot reproduce using JavaFX 17.0.10 or JavaFX 21.0.2 with Java 21.0.2 on Windows 10. Please provide a proper [mre], including environment details.

Comment: I had included the code in a minimal reproductible example and added the environment details. I also tried it on windows 10 and I don't reproduce the problem on this OS.

Comment: If possible, see if using a newer version of JavaFX (e.g., `17.0.10` or `21.0.2`) solves the issue. You may also want to try using a newer version of Java.

Comment: Does your target platform support the [`TRANSPARENT_WINDOW`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/21/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/ConditionalFeature.html#TRANSPARENT_WINDOW) feature?

Comment: Effectively, it is a platform problem. Platform.isSupported(ConditionakFeature.TRANSPARENT_WINDOW) returns false